# Night Mode specific Mipmaps

Tags: android, android-theme, android-mipmap

I am using the DayNight theme in my app. I know that most of the values can be modified to support this by using the "-night" tag ( like, drawables-night and colors-night). I tried the same for mipmap (mipmap-night) and it did not work. Is there a different way to handle app icons for DayNight theme? I am trying to make app icon change as the app theme changes.﻿

Comment: I think, you can put your icons in `drawable` folder instead of `mipmap`

Comment: `mipmap` is only to be used for the app launcher icon.

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin I will try that as my last choice. Because, when I use drawable app icons, they scale pretty differently on different launchers.

Comment: @Rotwang Exactly what I am trying to achieve. As my app has DayNight theme, I figured I could provide different app icons as well for Day and Night so that it matches the app theme.

Comment: I mean you don't need to change your icons to drawable. Just move your png icons to `drawable` and `drawable-night` folders

Comment: Moved everything to `drawable` and `drawable-night`. It still just loads the items in `drawable` and ignores the items in `drawable-night` irrespective of the app theme. Even when the launcher is set to Night Mode (tried in Nova), the night specific icons are ignored. I guess Android does not support changing icons based on the theme.